# How to keep menu visible with .hover when creating a drop-down menu

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I'm making a drop down (nav) menu. When a user hovers over the button "DROP" another div called "MENU" fades in under it, which will be the menu. How would I keep the div "MENU" shown because when the user moves the mouse off the button it disappears. Here's the jQuery code:

```
$("#DROP").hover(
  function () {
    $('#MENU').fadeIn('fast');
  }, 
  function () {
    $('#MENU').fadeOut('fast');
  }
);
```

How would I keep the "MENU" shown when the mouse is over it? THEN fade, when the mouse goes off it. And at the same time, make sure the "MENU" fades if the user doesn't put the mouse over it.

Comment: Just a friendly reminder that id's and class values should not begin with an upper case letter.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code as well, it should do the trick.

```
$('#MENU').hover(function () {
     $('#MENU').stop(); // stops current animation
     $('#MENU').show();
   },
   function () {
      $('#MENU').fadeOut('fast');
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make #MENU a child element of #DROP, so the mouseout event won't fire until the cursor has left both #DROP and #MENU.
See http://jsfiddle.net/jAHs2/2/ for an example.

Another alternative could be to use a combination of setTimeout/clearTimeout to call the fadeOut function so you can cancel it when the user hovers the submenu.

Answer (score 0):

Try subscribing to one more function like this,

```
var isInsideDrop = false;
$('#MENU').hover(function () {
     isInsideDrop = true; 
 $('#MENU').fadein('fast');
   },
   function () {
      $('#MENU').fadeOut('fast');
   }
);


 $('#MENU').mouseover(function(){
    if(isInsideDrop){
       $('#MENU').show();isInsideDrop = false;
    }
   });'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe one solution would be to add a delay to the fade-out effect. 1-2 Seconds should be long enough.

```
$("#DROP").hover(
    function () {
    $('#MENU').fadeIn('fast');
}, 

function () {
    $('#MENU').delay(2000).fadeOut('fast');
});
```